# NGINX Reverse Proxy upstream sent more data than specified in "Content-Length" header while reading upstream

Tags: reverse-proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy

So, i have a setup with authelia and another web application that im protecting with 2FA behind nginx reverse proxy.

Everything is working perfectly except one of the plugins inside the web application.

Nginx Proxy Manager gives me the following error and the page is blank:

023/09/28 10:04:50 [warn] 169#169: *85 upstream sent more data than specified in "Content-Length" header while reading upstream, client: XX.XX.XX.XX, server: domain.mydomain.com, request: "GET /console/plugins/1302/app_proxy/next-dashboard HTTP/2.0", upstream: "https://CC.CC.CC.CC:443/console/plugins/1302/app_proxy/next-dashboard", host: "domain.mydomain.com", referrer: "https://domain.mydomain.com/jsp/myapp.jsp"

Without the authelia in between app works fine with my nginx.

This is my configuration:

```
server {
  set $forward_scheme https;
  set $server         "IP";
  set $port           443;

  listen 80;
listen [::]:80;

listen 443 ssl http2;
listen [::]:443 ssl http2;


  server_name domain.mydomain.com;


  # Custom SSL
  ssl_certificate /cert.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /cert.pem;

proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
proxy_set_header Connection $http_connection;
proxy_http_version 1.1;


  access_log /data/logs/proxy-host-9_access.log proxy;
  error_log /data/logs/proxy-host-9_error.log warn;

location /authelia {
    internal;
    set $upstream_authelia http://IP/api/verify; #
    proxy_pass_request_body off;
    proxy_pass $upstream_authelia;    
    proxy_set_header Content-Length "";
 
    # Timeout if the real server is dead
    proxy_next_upstream error timeout invalid_header http_500 http_502 http_503;
    #proxy_buffering off;
    client_body_buffer_size 128k;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Original-URL $scheme://$http_host$request_uri;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr; 
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Uri $request_uri;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Ssl on;
    proxy_redirect  http://  $scheme://;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Connection "";
    proxy_cache_bypass $cookie_session;
    proxy_no_cache $cookie_session;
    proxy_buffers 4 256k;
    proxy_buffer_size 256k;
    send_timeout 5m;
    proxy_read_timeout 240;
    proxy_send_timeout 240;
    proxy_connect_timeout 240;
}
 
    location / {
        set $upstream_app https://IP:443;  
        proxy_pass $upstream_app;  
 
        auth_request /authelia;
        auth_request_set $target_url $scheme://$http_host$request_uri;
        auth_request_set $user $upstream_http_remote_user;
        auth_request_set $groups $upstream_http_remote_groups;
        proxy_set_header Remote-User $user;
        proxy_set_header Remote-Groups $groups;
        error_page 401 =302 https://auth.mydomain.com/?rd=$target_url; 
        client_body_buffer_size 128k;
        proxy_next_upstream error timeout invalid_header http_500 http_502 http_503;
 
        send_timeout 5m;
        proxy_read_timeout 360;
        proxy_send_timeout 360;
        proxy_connect_timeout 360;
 
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Uri $request_uri;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Ssl on;
        proxy_redirect  http://  $scheme://;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Connection "";
        proxy_cache_bypass $cookie_session;
        proxy_no_cache $cookie_session;
        proxy_buffer_size 256k;
        proxy_buffers 32 256k;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
            fastcgi_buffers 4 32k;


        real_ip_header X-Forwarded-For;
        real_ip_recursive on;
 
    }


large_client_header_buffers 4 8k;

  # Custom
  include /data/nginx/custom/server_proxy[.]conf;
}
```

Any ideas?
This config got messy since im trying a lot of cr@p the last 2 days.

I tried removing proxy buffer and the behavior was the same, i also added fastcgi_buffers but nothing happened.